# " booking of our sudent or for our student"? Are there any differences between American and Br english?

Tags: american-english, british-english

is there a difference between saying: "we would like to confirm the booking of our sudent or for our student"? Are there any differences between American and Br english?

It's supposed to be part of an email confirmation from one school to another, regarding a specific course

Comment: Are you asking the police or a hotel receptionist?

Comment: Hi Jim It's supposed to be part of an email confirmation from one school to another, regarding a specific course

Comment: Ah, then you want to confirm that your student is ***registered***

Comment: Not exactly; i want to confirm his acceptance or willingness to do the course and thus for the other school to reserve a space for him

Comment: So he’s teaching the course?

Comment: To take the course; sorry :(. He's a student who's going to take a summer course abroad.

Comment: That sounds like registration to me.  What makes you say it isn’t?

Comment: I want the school to proceed with the registration being that the student has agreed to the quotation; i guess that maybe the wording originally chosen is not the best!

Comment: @Jim Colloquialism vary. Do not worry. The Q is about the preposition, not a noun.

Comment: @RogerRodriguez Where are you from?

Comment: Yes! My question is precisely regarding the preposition! 

Comment: @Kris - Yes. Hence my first comment.  But I also think the choice of *verb* is important here.

Comment: I'm from costa rica but the word choice was done by an Italian; i think I would have phrase it differently..: